# Audio conversion to digital format

Tags: microcontroller, dac

I am confused in my understanding in implementation of voice guide for one of the instrument. I am trying to implement voice guide while operating one instrument. Audio data will be saved in memory ( No mic provision since data will be saved hard coded )

Hardware consists of DAC connected to controller and DAC's has inbuilt amplifier ( Please refer TLV320DAC Texas IC )
http://www.ti.com/product/TLV320DAC3100?keyMatch=TLV320DAC&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything

So, my question is how to get audio signal in digital format to save in memory?
Can we connect controller without DSP support to this DAC?

Please someone explain.
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a DAC (digital to analogue converter) for converting analogue audio to digital - you need an ADC (analogue to digital converter)

Comment: @Andy aka: Voice is not from Mic, its saved in some memory or controller.

Comment: Do you mean "how to get audio signal INTO digital format to save in memory" OR "how to get audio signal (that is already in digital format) to save in memory"?

Comment: how to get voice (analog) signal  INTO digital format to save in memory? Is there any conversion tool or we have to convert it in digital format and link it in program?

Comment: Use an ADC then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [DAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) or *Digital-to-Analog Converter*, converts digital bits into analog voltages, so that's what "plays" the already-recorded data. To generate this data, you could use an [ADC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) or *Analog-to-Digital Converter* to convert analog signals (voice) into digital data.

You may be able to use a computer to record the audio into digital form, and use that in programming the device initially. There are many ways to [encode voice data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_audio_coding_formats), ranging from uncompressed (raw values called PCM), all the way up to psycho-acoustically encoding (compression of perceived information) such as MP3 or AAC. The latter are more complex, but use less data.

Comment: You mean we can record voice signal in .mp3 or .wma format then add or link this file to my software program. Right?                           And, before dumping uncompressed voice data to our software code, can we compress it outside the code using some tool or so and then link compressed format to code.

Comment: Essentially, yes. Playback depends on the device doing the decoding. The [TLV320DAC3100](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv320dac3100.pdf#page=2) states that it has `25 Built-in Digital Audio Processing Blocks (PRB_P1 – 
PRB_P25) Providing Biquad and FIR Filters, DRC, and 3-D Structures` but these are not decoders for MP3 or WMA. So it is expecting raw (uncompressed) data. I'd suggest trying that first, as decompression of MP3 or WMA data adds much, much more complexity. There are IC's that will do it and more, such as the [VLSI 1003](http://www.vlsi.fi/en/products/vs1003.html).

Comment: how much length audio, it can store and play (TLV320DAC3100). I need 3-4 mins recording to be saved.

Comment: This DAC just converts data sent to it into voltages to be amplified and sent to a speaker as @crocboy states. The actual data is stored elsewhere, such as on a SD card or your "controller" (what controller are you using by the way?) Here are some links to other projects involving audio. [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/160), [Tiny PIC Player](http://dmitry.gr/index.php?r=05.Projects&proj=02.%20Single-chip%20audio%20Player), [Advanced dsPIC](http://www.uchobby.com/index.php/2008/07/21/dspic-wav-player/).

Comment: 4 minutes of PCM (uncompressed) audio, sampled at 44.1kHz, 16-bit resolution, 1 channel, will take up about: `bitrate = bitsPerSample * samplesPerSecond * channels` --> 16 * 44.1k * 1 = 705,600 bits/sec * (4min*60s) = 21.168MB. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556265/how-to-caluclate-audio-file-size).

Comment: we can store this audio data in flash memory conneccted to microcontroller through I2C/SPI. Right?

Comment: Absolutely. It then just becomes a matter ot programming the microcontroller to "read" the data from the flash, and stream it to the DAC fast enough that there are no glitches.

Comment: If possible, separate I2C or SPI busses may make things simpler, as the microcontroller can buffer some data and ensure that no interruptions happen.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S) is Wikipedia's entry about the \$I^2S\$ bus, and a [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/I2SBUS.pdf) datasheet about it. [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=i2s%20interface) knows all. :)

Answer (score 2):

This DAC takes a raw I2S stream - essentially this is "uncompressed" audio.  You send the raw value of each audio frame at the required sampling rate.  The implementation will depend on what format your audio is in on the memory.  You shouldn't need to do much DSP work - all you need to do is open the audio file, get the sample values, and send these over the I2S bus to the device.